# Delays due to new Magento Extension Quality Program?

Tags: marketplace

Magento extension submission guidelines do not mention Tech QA as a mandatory step. 
However, since yesterday I see following notice on extension review page on Magento Marketplace:

```
"As part of the Extension Quality Program we have added an automated production installation test and additional manual QA. With these new checks, we will need some time to properly evaluate all existing extensions first. This means that there are delays in our technical review process. We will be sure to notify you when all re-testing is complete."
```

This notice started appearing since yesterday only. 
Does it mean Magento will make much more delays for publishing an extension?
Does anybody know how much time Magento will take if we want to publish a new extension?

Answer (score 0):

I have a module in QA Review since 16/03 , and until today I didn't receive any news from Magento team.
To make your module published, it will take at least 2 months.

Comment: Yes it is frustrating at times.